# Why use "librejo" to mean bookstore?

Tags: word-formation

Learning Esperanto on Lernu.net, I've found that suffix *-ej-* is for space for placing something.

There are examples from this site:

```
lerni → lernejo = school
dormi → dormejo = bedroom
eliri → elirejo = exit
libro → librejo = book store
```

The first three are obvious.  But the last is not.  I think that a space for placing books is something like a book depository.  "Library" is not exact: In a library we can get books.  A book store, in my opinion, is the place where books are being sold. Placing books there is not the main purpose of this space.

So, why *librejo* is not as straightforward as other *-ej*-words?

Comment: I think “dormejo” and “librejo” are maybe just examples of the “ejo” suffix and don’t have such a precise meaning depending on the context. I learned the words “dormoĉarmbro” and “librovendejo” for these concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other examples

```
bakejo = bakery
```

Now form -ej' (ejo = loko) stems mainly from German -(er)ei (in French -erie and in English -ery).

```
bakejo = Bäckerei = backery = boulangerie
buĉejo = Metzgerei = butcher (store) = boucherie
```

So that the place is a store will be the case for sufficient -ej usages.

In fact `librejo` originally was used for the library (as building) too. For that however `biblioteko` nowadays is used.

There is also a famous (in linguistics) example of the opposite:

```
malsanulejo = hospitalo = hospital
hundejo = kennel
```

Here `malsanulejo` did gain the upper hand, and `hospitalo` is rare.

What might have irritated you, is that most versions have a *verbal* stem - not so `librejo`. That is not needed: `malsanulejo`.

Comment: Alia ekzemplo kun 'ejo': necesejo !